# Object doesn't support property or method 'setItem'

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm using the below code to store few contents in the webstorage object but I get this error:

> Error:-- Object doesn't support property or method 'setItem'

Any suggestion? I tried in both IE(11) and Chrome(Version 34.0.1847.131 m--latest version) and same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <body>        
        <div id="result">Test</div>            
        <script>
            // Check browser support
            alert(typeof(Storage))
            if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined")
            {
              // Store
              Storage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
              // Retrieve
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
            }
            else
            {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
            }
        </script>        
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Use localStorage instead of Storage.

Answer (score 1):

`Storage` and `localStorage` are differents.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage), here's a short definition of `Storage`:

> Storage is a SQLite database API. It is available to trusted callers, meaning extensions and Firefox components only.

So, in your case, you should use `localStorage` each time you used `Storage`.

Note that the getter and setter function are not mandatory, you can use `localStorage` as an object. For instance, all these lines produces the same result:

```
localStorage.foo = "bar";
localStorage["foo"] = "bar";
localStorage.setItem("foo","bar");
```

Comment: This is working for chrome, firefox. But not for IE ?? How to do that ib it :(